# Oracle Temp Table Space ASM Vs FileSystem

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have both FileSystem and ASM oracle DB, Now I am creating the temp table space I could do it in FileSystem db using the following sql.

```
" CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE AppTemp TEMPFILE '/db_data/my_db/temp01.dbf' SIZE 20M REUSE  EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL UNIFORM SIZE 16M"
```

Please explain how to achieve this in ASM, I have following syntax, searched on the net

```
"CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP TEMPFILE '+DATA1_A3' SIZE 100M
AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 100M MAXSIZE UNLIMITED EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL
UNIFORM SIZE 10M SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT MANUAL"
```

How does it allocates the db files to table space ?

Comment: What's the problem with this statement? Does it produce an error?

Comment: No.  I am new to ASM I would like to see the data file location for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP TEMPFILE '+DATA1_A3' SIZE 100M
AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 100M MAXSIZE UNLIMITED EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL
UNIFORM SIZE 10M SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT MANUAL" will create a tmeporary tablespace called temp made of a tempfile on DATA1_A3 diskgroup  witha system generated name. I suggest you to change it in : "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP TEMPFILE '+DATA1_A3' SIZE 100M" so you will use the default storage clauses of your database and version.

If you need to add another datafile, you can use the following command:
"ALTER TBALESPACE TEMP ADD TEMPFILE '+DATA1_A3' size nnnM"

If you need to modify the size of an existing datafile you have to retrieve de file name from dba_tempfiles or from asmcmd cli and then:
"ALTER DATABASE TEMPFILE 'FILEABSOLUTEASMPATH' RESIZE nnnnM"

Are you experiencing problem with this command?

regards
Giova

Comment: I don't have problem with statement, I want know the location of data file for this table space.

Comment: ??? @Malatesh: you can create the tablespace and then check the location... Normally it will be: +DG_NAME/DB_NAME/TEMPFILE/SYSTMEGENERATEDFILENAME for tenporary tablespace and +DG_NAME/DB_NAME/DATAFILE/SYSTMEGENERATEDFILENAME for normal datafile
Regards

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.